# .NET DateTimePicker class

Tags: .net, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm using a DateTimePicker in a form and then showing the date and time I pick in an textbox. My problem is that when I select a date the first time, it shows me something like:

```
11/05/2011 09:17:29 p.m.
```

Then I pick another date and it shows me this:

```
19/05/2011 09:17:29 p.m.
```

**Only the date is updated, why I can't update the time or how can I do it?**

I'm doing the update with this line of code:

```
fecha.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Is this in WinForms, ASP, or WPF?

Comment: Can you provide code about how you are updating the textbox

Comment: fecha.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();

Comment: @PachinSV are you initiating it like `dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now`? Also when you select the date do you expect it to update the time to current time or to 00:00 Hrs?

Comment: I'm not initiating the date picker with any value... and yes I was expecting update the time when I select another date.

Comment: If that's the case then you probably want to take care of updating the time part from your code. Let the user select the Date and append current time to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set `myDateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true` for it to show\update the time. In that case also, one has to change the time in ui to be reflected into your code.